# similar triangles, trigonometry and pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: the geometry problem]

This is a Rectangle (i didn't name it because it's not important), $ABD$ and $ABC$ are both right triangles, such that: $AB=5, BD=7, AC=9$
The question is to find the length of $MH$?

My Attempt:
First, calculate $AD$ and $BC$:
$$AD^{2} = BD^{2}-AB^{2} \Leftrightarrow AD = \sqrt{49-25}=\sqrt{24}$$
$$BC^{2}= AC^{2}-AB^{2} \Leftrightarrow BC = \sqrt{81-25}=\sqrt{56}$$

Now let's look at angles :
$$\tan{\alpha} = \frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{MH}{BH}=\frac{\sqrt{24}}{5}\Leftrightarrow MH = \frac{BH\sqrt{24}}{5}$$
$$\tan{\theta} = \frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{MH}{AH}=\frac{\sqrt{56}}{5}\Leftrightarrow MH = \frac{AH\sqrt{56}}{5}$$

This leaves us with the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}  MH = \frac{DH\sqrt{56}}{5}\\MH = \frac{AH\sqrt{24}}{5} \end{cases}$$
$$\implies \begin{cases}  MH = \frac{AD\sqrt{56}-\sqrt{56}AH}{5}\\MH = \frac{AH\sqrt{24}}{5} \end{cases}$$
$$\implies 5\sqrt{56}-AH\sqrt{56} = AH\sqrt{24}$$
and by some basic arithmetic we got:

$$AH = \frac{5\sqrt{56}}{\sqrt{24}+\sqrt{56}}$$
and now we will plug this result to one of the equations:
$$MH = \frac{5\sqrt{56}}{\sqrt{24}+\sqrt{56}} \cdot \sqrt{24} = \frac{7\sqrt{6}-3\sqrt{14}}{2}$$
But i still wondering if this answer is right because it appears to be irrational?

Any Help will be appreciate

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct. One thing I just need to say is that your figure is a bit confusing: $BC$ is longer than $AB$...

Comment: Yeah i make it quickly. Thank you for your answer

Comment: In the line with $\tan \alpha$ you switched from $BH$ to $DH$. The answer is still irrational

Comment: Why were you not expecting irrationalities to appear?

Comment: I have fixed the mistake, Andrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon a nice observation, while trying to see for a more straight forward solution.

From triangle similarity, we get

$\frac{HB}{AB} = \frac{MH}{AD}$ and $\frac{AH}{AB} = \frac{MH}{BC}$

adding the two

$\frac{HB}{AB} + \frac{AH}{AB} = \frac{MH}{AD} + \frac{MH}{BC}$
, then

$\frac{1}{MH} = \frac{1}{AD} + \frac{1}{BC} $,

Which is interesting because it says the length of $MH$ is independent $AB$,

Now you can solve for AD and BC with pythagorian theorem and find $MH$

...

$AD = \sqrt{24}$ and $BC=\sqrt{56}$

$\frac{1}{MH} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{24}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{56}}$

$MH = \frac{\sqrt{24}\sqrt{56}}{\sqrt{56}+\sqrt{24}}$